# Geopandas intersection causes 'Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing' error

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, bokeh, geopandas

I have some data about the city of baltimore broken down by zip code. the zip codes are bigger than the city limits, so I used the intersection of the zip code shapefiles and the convex hull of an outline of the city to trim them down.

And that works fine in Geopandas ... but when I try to bring that data into Bokeh as a Google Maps overlay, it breaks the BokehJS library. somehow.

If I map the zip code data or the city hull alone, it works fine. But plotting the intersection throws `Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing` in the html file.

Here's the python code that causes the problems:

```
data = hulled
metric = 'Arrest Count'

colors = inferno(100)
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=data[metric].min(), high=data[metric].max())

gsource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=data.to_json())
output_file('hulled_first.html')

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=39.2904, lng=-76.6122, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

p = gmap(***API KEY REMOVED***, map_options, title="hulled")

p.patches(xs='x', ys='y', source=gsource,
         fill_color={'field': metric, 'transform':mapper},
         fill_alpha=0.5, line_color="black", line_width=0.05)

show(p)
```

The broken html/javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {

                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('56a1700d-9c6a-4089-8f6e-ccb1746f079e').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"docid":"4cd841f2-2f0d-478e-93d2-e999b5fefb28","roots":{"1403726c-53aa-434b-96d9-2b33f365193c":"f700c6a2-1b69-4409-8c65-562639e2b79d"}}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>
```

and the console output looks like this:

```
bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
    at c (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at Object.h.project_xsys (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at e.t.set_data (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at t.set_data (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at t.initialize (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at t [as constructor] (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at t [as constructor] (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at t [as constructor] (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at new t (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
    at Object.i.build_views (bokeh-0.13.0.min.js:31)
```

Comment: Could you test the code snippet in this comment: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5351#issuecomment-253788091

Comment: Or another possibility: see the "Diagnosing possible errors" section in https://p-mckenzie.github.io/python/2017/12/01/embedding-bokeh-with-github-pages/ (it mentions the error you also see)